# How to add target line in Line chart - AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine, android-graphview

Is there any way I can add a target line in a Line Chart?

I want to draw green line shown in bar char image.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Target line image]

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have updated question and also attached the image for better understanding.

Comment: So, you mean "quote lines". Because a "target" is something you shoot at. Or a goal to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

We can use combinechart to get the target line.

```
// Specifying chart types to be drawn in the graph
// Number of data series and number of types should be same
// Order of data series and chart type will be same
String[] types = new String[] { LineChart.TYPE, BarChart.TYPE };

ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, types);
```

This will create chart with Line chart and Bar chart.

Tutorial : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-combined-chart-using-achartengine-library/